# The design of column Name does not provide for sorting the view as requested in Xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Our customized XPages name picker started to throw following error. It was all working fine with Domino 852 FP4 but after our upgrade to Domino 853 FP3, its starting to throw following error. Its complaining about sort column in View control referring to Names.nsf. We still got Domino 852 FP4 and all works good on old box but not with Domino 853 FP3. Has any one else faced similar problems?

The design of column Name does not provide for sorting the view as requested.

▼ Stack Trace

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: The design of column Name does not provide for sorting the view as requested.
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.viewnavigator.AbstractViewCollectionNavigator.readEntries(AbstractViewCollectionNavigator.java:95)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoViewEntryArray.readEntries(DominoViewEntryArray.java:104)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.readViewEntries(DominoViewDataContainer.java:548)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.getRowCount(DominoViewDataContainer.java:527)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataModel.getRowCount(DominoViewDataModel.java:109)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager$PagerState.<init>(UIPager.java:76)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager$PagerState.<init>(UIPager.java:71)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager.createPagerState(UIPager.java:540)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.XPagerRenderer.encodeChildren(XPagerRenderer.java:67)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.processPagerCell(ViewPanelRenderer.java:656)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.encodeBegin(ViewPanelRenderer.java:354)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:788)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataEx.encodeBegin(UIDataEx.java:413)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewPanel.encodeBegin(UIViewPanel.java:288)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:840)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:641)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:320)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:335)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:248)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:653)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:476)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
NotesException: The design of column Name does not provide for sorting the view as requested.
    lotus.domino.local.View.FTSearchSorted(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.viewnavigator.FTViewNavigatorEx.createCollection(FTViewNavigatorEx.java:79)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.viewnavigator.AbstractViewCollectionNavigator.readEntries(AbstractViewCollectionNavigator.java:76)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoViewEntryArray.readEntries(DominoViewEntryArray.java:104)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.readViewEntries(DominoViewDataContainer.java:548)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.getRowCount(DominoViewDataContainer.java:527)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataModel.getRowCount(DominoViewDataModel.java:109)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager$PagerState.<init>(UIPager.java:76)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager$PagerState.<init>(UIPager.java:71)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager.createPagerState(UIPager.java:540)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.XPagerRenderer.encodeChildren(XPagerRenderer.java:67)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.processPagerCell(ViewPanelRenderer.java:656)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.encodeBegin(ViewPanelRenderer.java:354)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:788)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataEx.encodeBegin(UIDataEx.java:413)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewPanel.encodeBegin(UIViewPanel.java:288)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:840)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:641)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:320)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:335)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:248)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:653)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:476)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tick the box in the view column properties of the view that allows resorting

Comment: Thanks. But where is resorting option in the view column properties?? Did you mean Sort --> Ascending / Descending??

Comment: I couldn't find the exact APAR (for several minutes), but want to share the fact, that show single category trick has serious performance problem if category contains multiple values - documents show up in more than one category.

Comment: Yes, sort on click and yes every feature comes with a cost

Comment: Thanks stwissel. It resolved the problem but I don't know if it is good to change names.nsf --> people view design. I am going to raise this with IBM to listen to what they going to advice.  Thanks a lot..

Comment: you might consider to use a bean with a collection to do all the sorting - keep it in memory (and you are free to accept the answer)